# flutter_libserialport not able to recoganize port /dev/ttyS0

Tags: flutter

I am creating a flutter desktop app for linux. The app also requires to connect to serial port to get more information. I have written similar code in python and it is able to recognize /dev/ttyS0. Similar code in flutter it is not recoganizing the path.

Does flutter_libserialport support linux? Is there something I am missing?

> SerialPortError (SerialPortError: No such file or directory, errno =
> 2)

```
SerialPort port = SerialPort("/dev/ttyS0");
    final config = SerialPortConfig();
    config.baudRate = 115200;
    config.parity = 1;
    config.stopBits = 1;
    port.config = config;
    SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port, timeout: 10000);

    int bufferIndex = 0;

    Stream<Uint8List> upcomingData = reader.stream.map((data) {
      return data;
    });
```